# Laravel 5 Language specific path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I use laravel 5.1

I have 2 images:

test_de.png 
test_en.png

Depending on the current language it should choose the correct image.

I try this:

```
  <img src="{{asset('site/images/test_{{Config::get('app.locale')}}.png')}}">
```

This not works, because it will not be parsed correctly. Any ideas why? Thank you

Comment: you cant use {{ inside {{.

Comment: Ok, how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="{{asset('site/images/test_'.Config::get('app.locale').'.png')}}">
```